# Can you identify this tree?

Tags: botany, species-identification

[image]

This was photographed near Budapest, Hungary, though my friend said she'd only ever seen these in the USA before.

Comment: A question about the same plant: [Viburnum](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58958/what-is-this-small-tree).

Comment: Yes this is definitely another example of a *Viburnum* like the one in [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58958/16866). Without additional pictures, I'm not sure we'll be able to identify it *accurately* to species/cultivar. As such, -- even though it appears to be a different species/cultivar -- I'm going to vote to close this as a duplicate of the linked post.